# Is there a way to delete previously plotted lines when using a variable length array to instantiate lines?

Tags: pine-script

In my script I am collecting pivots as the bars progress, filtering them, and now want to draw lines for the present levels:

```
if array.size(mpivots) > 0
    for i = 0 to array.size(mpivots) - 1
        pivot = array.get(mpivots, i)
        ln = line.new(bar_index, pivot, bar_index - 1, pivot, extend=extend.both)
```

I have tried the following:

1. Generate a var array of lines and then iterate through and delete before reassigning. Iterating through, assigning the line to an identifier `ln = array.get(lines, i)` and then deleting `line.delete(ln[1])`.
2. Save my list of pivots as a copy to a var-instantiated array and recreate the lines, then delete them, before generating new lines.

Is there a work-around? I'm aware I could do something for say, the highest N or lowest N pivots manually, but if I want to plot all of the pivot levels and my number of pivots changes from bar to bar, is there no solution? Is there a way to dynamically generate identifiers so I could regenerate them and delete them on the next bar?

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you only want to draw the most recent pivot that you collected? If not, could you please clarify?

Comment: Thanks for responding Bjorn.

1. I collect pivots levels, volumes, and indicies in three arrays, and increment the indices each bar.
2. I remove pivots, levels volumes and indicies from their arrays if the index is greater than a certain limit, say 50.
3. Each bar I take the current pivots and volumes and use a function to generate new arrays of pivot levels and volumes. Basically combines pivots within a certain proximity and defines a new price level based on the comparative volumes.
4. Display the newly generated price levels, without displaying the levels generated on the last bar.

Comment: If my previous comment doesn't make sense it could be considered this way: Say I magically have an array or floats given to me every bar, it's a different size each time. I want to plot a horizontal line for each float, so I can see the present levels of the float values, which means I must have a way to delete the previously plotted lines.

Comment: Could you update your question and add the complete script you currently have please?